# Rust: How to use a value in a Stream adapter without cloning it twice

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Currently, I am trying to print a counter value when my stream receives a new value:

```rust
fn add_counter_to_stream<T: std::marker::Send + 'static>(
    stream: PinnedStream<T>,
) -> PinnedStream<T> {
    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0)); // Shared counter between threads
    futures::StreamExt::boxed(stream.map({
        let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
        move |value| {
            let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
            async move {
                // Print counter value and increment
                let mut num = counter.lock().await;
                println!("Counter: {}", *num);
                *num += 1;
            };
            value
        }
    }))
}
```

However as seen above, the code doesn't compile unless I create two nested closures and use `Arc::clone(&counter)` twice. Is there a way to refactor it so it is done in one clone operation, and why do I need two closures in this example?

Comment: To be clear, you're only creating one nested closure. The second "closure" is an `async` block, which is a future, not a function.

Comment: You also never do anything with the future generated by the `async` block, so the entire `async` block is redundant.

Answer (score 5):

You're overthinking this a bit.

All you need is for the mapping function to own a mutable counter.  The mapping function used by `StreamExt::map` does not return a future, but rather a value.  This means you don't have to worry about a future capturing the lifetime of the counter.

You can do this without `Arc` and without `Mutex`:

```
fn add_counter_to_stream<T: std::marker::Send + 'static>(
    stream: PinnedStream<T>,
) -> PinnedStream<T> {
    let mut counter = 0;

    stream
        .map(move |value| {
            println!("Counter: {}", counter);
            counter += 1;
            value
        })
        .boxed()
}
```

Note that you do not have separate threads here, because the mapping function is run in series as items are pulled from the stream.